# How to show a contact form after 10 seconds using Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my current code and it pops up when clicked but i want to be able to have it pop up after being on the page for 10 seconds as well. Any guidance would be very helpful as i keep breaking it.

```
<script>
  $("#fixed-form-container .body").hide();
$("#fixed-form-container .button").click(function () {
        $(this).next("#fixed-form-container div").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10 * 1000 /* milliseconds */);`

Comment: Use `setTimeout` inside a `window.onload = function() {  }` function

Comment: I haev this now but it is not working     onclick="myClick();"

 function myClick() {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
     document.getElementById('#fixed-form-container').style.display='none';
    }, 1000);
}

  $("#fixed-form-container .body").hide();
$("#fixed-form-container .button").click(function () {
        $(this).next("#fixed-form-container div").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    });
</script>